# Scala Collection sorted, sortWith and sortBy Performance

Tags: performance, list, scala, sorting, collections

Scala includes several methods in the standard library for sorting a list, for example to sort the list *list*, one can use:

```
list.sorted
list.sortWith(_<_)
list.sortBy(x=>x)
```

While these might be the simplest ways to sort a list, I found that for larger lists, they have significant performance drawback.

For example, to sort one million integers, sorted takes on average 500ms, while sortWith and sortBy  take around 700ms. This is compared to scala.util.Sorting.quickSort which takes around 120ms and java.util.Arrays.sort which takes around 100ms. For larger lists, this multiple factor difference is observed as we scale further. The pattern is shown in the following chart.

[image: Performance of various Scala sorting methods]

What is the reason for this lag in performance? And why aren't more efficient algorithms/implementations used for the standard methods?

Comment: In addition to what wingedsubmariner explained, note that quicksort is not a stable sort. The easy sorts, which are fine for small numbers of elements, are stable sorts that leave the original data alone and work on all collection types. Quicksort is a non-stable, in-place sort on Arrays, for better performance -- worth the effort to use if you have lots of items.

Answer (score 25):

Notice how the lines have the same slope, but are offset from each other? With the logarithmic scale, we're looking at a constant factor difference. `sorted` and friends pay the cost of converting a `List` to an `Array`, sorting (with `java.util.Arrays.sort`, in fact), and converting back to `List`. `scala.util.Sorting.quickSort` and `java.util.Arrays.sort` operate on arrays directly. The `log n` factor in quicksort's `n log n` performance is largely irrelevant, so with the linear time needed to create the Array and the resulting list we end up with a constant factor difference. Five times worse performance might looking horrible, but remember the `List` has a cons cell for each element, which makes for massive amounts of random access when creating the `Array`, and then creating the new `List` requires time spent allocating memory, and in all likelihood, a garbage collection cycle or two.

For lists of primitives, it's even worse. `List` is generic, so any primitives must be boxed, which adds another layer of indirection. And unfortunately the `Array` that is created holds boxed values as well. Effectively, you end up sorting an `Array[java.lang.Integer]` when you really want to be sorting an `Array[Int]`.

To summarize: the sorting algorithms are identical, but there are good reasons why mutable arrays outperform immutable singly-linked lists.

Comment: Aren't you actually looking at an order of magnitude difference each time, not a constant difference

Comment: @monkjack - A constant multiplicative factor (e.g. 10x).

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but I tried including the toArray/toList conversions in the time measurement for quickSort and java sort, and for the one million record case I see only 20ms increase while the 500ms difference remains. Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: @deepkimo Yes, see my new edit. The Array that is created is holding boxed values, so it is much slower to sort.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner ok, doing list.map(new java.lang.Integer(_)).toArray gets the time close, but java.util.Arrays.sort takes Array[Int] and not Array[Integer], so not sure why starting from 'sorted' it ends up using Array[Integer], while using it directly I need to pass Array[Int]?

Comment: @deepkimo It uses the `sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` form of `java.util.Arrays.sort`, which is much slower. Don't do `list.map(new java.lang.Integer(_)).toArray`, the `Int`s don't need to be boxed a second time.