# Fastest sorting for Vectors with small, limited number of elements

Tags: scala, sorting, vector, scalac

I have a immutable `Vector` of a class called `Vector3`, with max 8 elements, no matter what. I can calculate a `vector3.length`, which will yield a `Double`.

My question is how to sort this `Vector[Vector3]` the fastest way possible.

What I used until now:

```
vectors.sortWith((a, b) => a.length < b.length)
```

I am pretty sure this approach has massive overhead (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there a faster way in my case?

Comment: I'd be tempted by the more concise `sortBy(_.length)` but [they appear to be equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588615/scala-collection-sorted-sortwith-and-sortby-performance).

Comment: `Vector` should have pretty good asymptotic behavior but has a pretty big constant factor. If performance is critical I doubt that you should be using lots of 8 element Vectors.

Comment: @Jasper-M what would you recommend instead?

Comment: Arrays, maybe. But benchmark, benchmark, benchmark.

Comment: ^ What @TheArchetypalPaul said.